# Show all attachments one by one via a next button on the attachment itself that opens

Tags: angularjs

I have these functions that show me all the attachments at once and what I want is for them to be opened one at a time and the next one to be shown through a next button on the attachment that is displayed but I can't do it.

```
         $scope.previsualizarTodosAdjuntos = function() {
            var ultimaPosicion = $scope.datos.adjuntos.preguntasAdjuntos.length - 1;
            var preguntasUltimaPosicion = $scope.datos.adjuntos.preguntasAdjuntos[ultimaPosicion].preguntas;
            
            var idDetalles = preguntasUltimaPosicion.map(pregunta => pregunta.idDetalle);
            
            console.log(idDetalles);
            
            idDetalles.forEach(function(idDetalle) {
                $scope.funciones.previsualizarTodosAdjunto({ idDetalle: idDetalle }); 
            });
            
        };
```

```
              previsualizarTodosAdjunto: function (params, BBASE64) {
                params = {
                  SSISTEMA: "",
                  IEMPRESA: kUtil.empresa,
                  IPRESUPUESTO: $scope.datos.presupuesto.presupuesto,
                  IDETALLEPREGUNTA: params.idDetalle,
                  BBASE64: true,
                };
                $scope.servicios.servicioPrevisualizarTodosAdjunto(params);
              },
```

```
              servicioPrevisualizarTodosAdjunto: function (params, ev) {
                ServicioNuevoPresupuesto.descargarAdjunto(params).then(function (ok) {

                  var nameImg = ok.data.value.Rows[0].NOMBRE;
                  var urlArchive = ok.data.value.Rows[0].DATA;
                  console.log(urlArchive)
                  var archiveBase64 = ok.data.value.Rows[0].BASE64;
                  var allowedExtensions = ["jpg", "jpeg", "png", "gif", "pdf"];
                  var lastDotIndex = nameImg.lastIndexOf('.');
                  var fileExtension = nameImg.substring(lastDotIndex + 1).toLowerCase();

                  if (allowedExtensions.includes(fileExtension)) {
                    if (fileExtension === "pdf") {
                        var byteCharacters = atob(archiveBase64);
                        var byteNumbers = new Array(byteCharacters.length);
                        for (var i = 0; i < byteCharacters.length; i++) {
                          byteNumbers[i] = byteCharacters.charCodeAt(i);
                        }
                        var byteArray = new Uint8Array(byteNumbers);
                        var pdfBlob = new Blob([byteArray], { type: "application/pdf" });
                        var pdfUrl = URL.createObjectURL(pdfBlob);

                        var confirmDialog = $mdDialog.confirm();

                        confirmDialog._options.template =
                        '<md-dialog>' +
                        '<md-dialog-content>' +
                          '<iframe src="' + pdfUrl + '" style="width: 149vh; height: 71vh;"></iframe>' +
                        '</md-dialog-content>' +
                        '<md-dialog-actions>' +
                          '<md-button ng-click="dialog.abort()" >' +
                          'Cerrar' +
                        '</md-button>' +
                        '</md-dialog-actions>' +
                      '</md-dialog>',

                      $mdDialog.show(confirmDialog)
                        
                    } else {

                        var confirmDialog = $mdDialog.confirm();

                        confirmDialog._options.template =
                        '<md-dialog>' +
                        '<md-dialog-content>' +
                          '<img src="' + urlArchive + '" alt="' + nameImg + '" style="max-width: 100%;">' +
                        '</md-dialog-content>' +
                        '<md-dialog-actions>' +
                          '<md-button ng-click="dialog.abort()" class="md-primary">' +
                            'Cerrar' +
                          '</md-button>' +
                        '</md-dialog-actions>' +
                      '</md-dialog>',
              
                      $mdDialog.show(confirmDialog)
                    
                    }
                  } 
                  
                });
              },
```

I have tried with promises but it doesn't work for me.

I have also tried it with control variables and there is no way

Answer (score 0):

you have to add an index var

```
$scope.currentAttachmentIndex = 0;
```

now show just the index attachment

```
$scope.previsualizarTodosAdjuntos = function() {
    var idDetalles = $scope.datos.adjuntos.preguntasAdjuntos[$scope.currentAttachmentIndex].preguntas.map(pregunta => pregunta.idDetalle);
    $scope.funciones.previsualizarTodosAdjunto({ idDetalle: idDetalles[0] }); 
};
```

Update your dialog templates to include a "Next" button:

```
'<md-dialog-actions>' +
  '<md-button ng-click="dialog.next()" >' +
  'Next' +
  '</md-button>' +
  '<md-button ng-click="dialog.abort()" >' +
  'Cerrar' +
  '</md-button>' +
'</md-dialog-actions>'
```

handle the next button

```
$mdDialog.show(confirmDialog).then(function(result) {
    if (result === 'next') {
        $scope.currentAttachmentIndex++;
        if ($scope.currentAttachmentIndex < $scope.datos.adjuntos.preguntasAdjuntos.length) {
            $scope.previsualizarTodosAdjuntos();
        } else {
            $scope.currentAttachmentIndex = 0; // Reset or handle end of list
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: The problem is that the dialog box opens but it seems that it does not take the result into account, it does not enter the console.log                       $mdDialog.show(confirmDialog).then(function(result) { console.log(result)

Comment: add a .catch(function(error) {
    console.log("Rejected with:", error);
}); at the end of $mdDialog

Comment: When I hit close it does go into the console.log of the error but if I hit next it does nothing